# Sparse matrix conversion in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to develop a program in C to convert a sparse matrix file into a dense matrix. From what I've read, the best approach would be the use of linked lists but I have no experience with them and haven't found a good online resource explaining the subject. I'm not looking for a quick solution but rather a website or text source that can explain how the process works so I can apply it to this project. What resources I have seen, suggest using three arrays to handle the values in the matrix (The row, column, and individual value) and two arrays for the vector (one for the row, the other for the column). Thanks!

Comment: What format is the data in the source file.

Comment: The input file will contain no unnecessary formatting and will be strictly populated with the necessary values in a series. The first two values in the matrix file will indicate the dimensions, in terms of rows and columns, with the rest of the values being the needed data. For example, if I had a 10x10 matrix, the first two values would be 10 and 10, followed by another 100 elements to be used as data. I must convert the sparse matrix into a densely populated matrix so I can perform matrix-vector multiplication, so both the matrix and the vector must undergo the conversion.

Comment: However, I've already designed an algorithm for the multiplication so that aspect is finished. After the initial two values, the rest of the file will list the values in sequence but will be stored in a one dimensional array after conversion. I'm sorry if this isn't clear, since the concept is still very abstract to me.

Comment: Why linked lists?  Isn't the basic procedure to allocate a big array to represent the dense matrix, then read through the sparse matrix representation, populating the various elements of the dense matrix's array?

Comment: For this particular project, I need to maximize performance and efficient processing time while ensuring that the algorithm performs as few calculations as possible. Thus, linked lists are the preferred method for handling the matrix in this situation. I don't know enough about the process to give a better answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Strata: This doesn't make sense.  A dense matrix, by definition, is a big array.  How do linked lists fit into the picture?  Who told you this?

Comment: @Strata: I'm with @Oli here. If you are converting to a "dense array", then just load data from the file directly into such an array. You can use linked lists as one way to implement a sparse array. But, based on your question, that's not what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file format you've specified is for a dense matrix. A 10x10 matrix with 100 elements is dense. A sparse matrix has fewer than n*m elements and all "missing" elements are assumed to be 0. The point of doing it this way is so that matrices that are almost all zero (which happens in a lot of applications) will use less space. But using a sparse matrix format to store a dense matrix will use far more space than just a plain array.

One common sparse matrix file format is called MatrixMarket and it looks very similar to what you described. The first line has three values, # of rows, # of columns, # of nonzero elements (called `nnz`). Then you have nnz lines of the actual elements in a triplet: `(row #) (column #) (value)`
If your sparse matrix is in a similar format then you don't need any sparse matrix in memory. Just scan the values and fill in your dense array directly.

If you do want to have a sparse matrix in memory then there are several options for how to store it. Triplets is the easiest, and it's just an in-memory version of the MatrixMarket file. 3 arrays, or 1 array of structs.
The most common structure for linear algebra operations is Compressed Sparse Columns (CSC) or Compressed Sparse Rows (CSR). I'll let you look that up, but if you want a C implementation to play with you should look at Tim Davis' [CSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/). This is also how MatLAB stores sparse matrices, Tim was one of the people who wrote that part of MatLAB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a linked list may not be what you're looking for, but [this site](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/) offers a pretty comprehensive tutorial on the subject.  It may help shed some light on whether or not it would be appropriate for your problem...  Good luck!